# Java 2D Collision?

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection

Hey guys i'm making a 2D java game and i'm trying to figure out how to make a good collision code. I am currently using the following code:

```
    public void checkCollision() {
    Rectangle player_rectangle = new Rectangle(player.getX(),player.getY(),32,32);

    for(Wall wall : walls) {

        Rectangle wall_rectangle = new Rectangle(wall.getX(), wall.getY(), 32,32);

        if (player_rectangle.intersects(wall_rectangle)) {
            Rectangle intersection = (Rectangle) player_rectangle.createIntersection(wall_rectangle);

            if (player.xspeed > 0) {
                player.x -= intersection.getWidth();
            }

            if (player.yspeed > 0) {
                player.y -= intersection.getHeight();
            }

            if (player.xspeed < 0) {
                player.x += intersection.getWidth();
            }

            if (player.yspeed < 0) {
                player.y += intersection.getHeight(); 
            }

            Print(Integer.toString(intersection.width) + ", " + Integer.toString(intersection.height));

        }

    }

}
```

With this code it works fine if you are press one button but if press down and left for example the player will fly off in some random direction.

Here is a picture of the types of maps I have:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you to use box2d for java instead of doing yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Smooth 2D Rectangle collision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753549/java-smooth-2d-rectangle-collision)

Comment: I have flagged this as a duplicate of your previous thread.  If it is not a duplicate (for some reason I missed) it would be smart to explain why.

Comment: The other post contains different code, I don't know if that gave me the right to create another post but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is in assuming that the player is running directly into the wall. Consider the case where there is a wall rect (100,100,32,32) and the player is at (80,68,32,32). The player is moving down and to the left, so player.xspeed < 0 and player.yspeed > 0; say the next position for the player is (79,69,32,32). The intersection is then (100,100,11,1).

Note that although the player is moving left (as well as down) the wall is actually to the right of the player. This line:

```
if (player.xspeed < 0) {
    player.x += intersection.getWidth();
}
```

... causes player.x to be set to 90 in a sudden jump.

One thing you could do is check that the player's left-hand side was contained in the intersection, i.e.

```
if (player.xspeed < 0 && player.x >= intersection.x) {
    player.x += intersection.getWidth();
}
```

Obviously a similar thing needs to be done for the other directions too.

Comment: So would I use the code you gave instead of mine? or add it in with the exisiting code.