# Java 2D Collision

Tags: java, collision-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java 2D Collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763244/java-2d-collision)

Hey guys I have another post regarding this which has just gone dead so I thought i'd try get some fresh answers regarding this.

I'm trying to get my collision detection to work. My collision detection works fine when i come side on to my map blocks, and fine when I only hold up or down and hit a block from the top or bottom. But when i hold up or down aswell as right or left and hit a block from the top or bottom it will go off in funny directions.

Small Video of me demonstrating (Sorry if it's not clear): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ILccRtw8ME Hopefully this helps alot.

If you didn't watch the video here is a picture of the map's I will be using:

[image]

Here is my current collision code:

```
    public void checkCollision() {
    Rectangle player_rectangle = new Rectangle(player.getX(),player.getY(),32,32);

    for(Wall wall : walls) {

        Rectangle wall_rectangle = new Rectangle(wall.getX(), wall.getY(), 32,32);

        if (player_rectangle.intersects(wall_rectangle)) {
            Rectangle intersection = (Rectangle) player_rectangle.createIntersection(wall_rectangle);


            if (player.xspeed < 0 && player.x >= intersection.x) {
                player.x += intersection.getWidth();
            } else {

            if (player.xspeed > 0 && player.x <= intersection.x) {
                player.x -= intersection.getWidth();
            } else {

            if (player.yspeed < 0 && player.y >= intersection.y) {
                player.y += intersection.getHeight();
            }else {

            if (player.yspeed > 0 && player.y <= intersection.y) {
                player.y -= intersection.getHeight();
            }
            }
            }
            }



            Print(Integer.toString(intersection.width) + ", " + Integer.toString(intersection.height));

        }

    }

}
```

All help will be appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Isn't it the same question you asked on your [older post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763244/java-2d-collision)? If yes, please edit and/or start bounty on your last question and don't repost it. if not, please explain the problem with more details.

Comment: +1 for a funny video. block warping ftw.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut What do you mean funny? :L

Comment: Maybe it died because you chose to ignore my [advice from 2 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753549/java-smooth-2d-rectangle-collision).  Voting to close.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I honestly don't know what that SSCCE thing is..

Comment: That is why.  1) I told you about it.  2) I linked to it when I first told you about it.  3) I linked to the thread where it is linked, when I mentioned it on this thread.  But then, can you honestly not use a search engine?  The top hit is to one of the mirrors.

Answer (score 3):

This is my first attempt at answering a question on StackOverflow so please be patient with me. I will try and structure this answer by first diagnosing the problem, finding the symptoms that may cause your problem and lastly, present a solution and see if it works with you.

First, let me format your code with the correct level of indentation so that we have a more clear picture of what is going on.

```
public void checkCollision() {
    Rectangle player_rectangle = new Rectangle(player.getX(),
            player.getY(), 32, 32);

    for (Wall wall : walls) {

        Rectangle wall_rectangle = new Rectangle(wall.getX(), wall.getY(),
                32, 32);

        if (player_rectangle.intersects(wall_rectangle)) {
            Rectangle intersection = (Rectangle) player_rectangle
                    .createIntersection(wall_rectangle);

            if (player.xspeed < 0 && player.x >= intersection.x) {
                player.x += intersection.getWidth();
            } else {

                if (player.xspeed > 0 && player.x <= intersection.x) {
                    player.x -= intersection.getWidth();
                } else {

                    if (player.yspeed < 0 && player.y >= intersection.y) {
                        player.y += intersection.getHeight();
                    } else {

                        if (player.yspeed > 0 && player.y <= intersection.y) {
                            player.y -= intersection.getHeight();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Print(Integer.toString(intersection.width) + ", "
                    + Integer.toString(intersection.height));

        }

    }

}
```

Now that we have done this, it becomes more clear what you are doing. The first thing I noticed is that you are nesting your conditional statement. To clarify, you are doing this:

```
    if (condition){
    // do something
    else{
        if(anotherCondition){
            // do something
            else{
                //etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you should be doing is using multiple conditional statements in a row like this:

```
if (condition){
    //do something
}

if (anotherCondition){
    //do something else
}

//etc
```

This is because if you have two case, such as you being in the bottom left corner, you will need to execute the conditions for the intersection to the left as well as intersection to the bottom. However, this is irrelevant for your example since you go through each wall individually.

So why is this important?

Well, it seems to me that if the first condition is not satisfied, then all the other conditions will not execute. If `player.xspeed < 0 && player.x >= intersection.x` returns `true`, then even if the other 3 statements nested in it returns `true`, they will not be executed because it relies on that first statement being `false`. Therefore when you go to an edge, where two or more of the cases would be true, you only get one of them executed.

Therefore my proposed solution, based on all the above is this:

```
public void checkCollision() {
        Rectangle player_rectangle = new Rectangle(player.getX(),
                player.getY(), 32, 32);

        for (Wall wall : walls) {

            Rectangle wall_rectangle = new Rectangle(wall.getX(), wall.getY(),
                    32, 32);

            if (player_rectangle.intersects(wall_rectangle)) {
                Rectangle intersection = (Rectangle) player_rectangle
                        .createIntersection(wall_rectangle);

                if (player.xspeed < 0 && player.x >= intersection.x) {
                    player.x += intersection.getWidth();
                } 

                if (player.xspeed > 0 && player.x <= intersection.x) {
                    player.x -= intersection.getWidth();
                }

                if (player.yspeed < 0 && player.y >= intersection.y) {
                    player.y += intersection.getHeight();
                }

                if (player.yspeed > 0 && player.y <= intersection.y) {
                    player.y -= intersection.getHeight();
                }

                Print(Integer.toString(intersection.width) + ", "
                        + Integer.toString(intersection.height));

            }

        }

    }
```

Try this out and see if it works. If it does not, then we can take it from there and see how to improve and fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying, sadly it doesn't work as well now using that code :L It jumps around randomly even when coming from right or left and holding up / down

Comment: Interesting. I might need to edit my answer shortly. Need to think about it further.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a bunch of unit tests for all the different states you can imagine that `checkCollision` needs to deal with. 
This way, you'll:

- Easily find out which specific inputs are causing the block to jump (because unit tests are short and well-contained)
- **Ensure that this functionality won't be broken** by future changes (because unit tests are run with each build)

A sample unit test for this would look something like this:

```
public class CollisionTests {

    @Test
    public void hitFromLeftHeadOn() throws Exception {
        List<Wall> walls = Lists.newArrayList(
            new Wall( ... ), // south wall
            new Wall( ... ), // east wall
            // etc.
        );
        Player player = new Player(...);

        // Set player to collide with the east wall head on
        player.setX(...);
        player.setY(...);
        player.setXSpeed(...);
        player.setYSpeed(...);

        checkCollision();

        // Now check if the checkCollision method worked properly
        assertEquals("Player's x coordinate should be set to ...", ..., player.getX());
        assertEquals("Player's y coordinate should be set to ...", ..., player.getY());
    }
```

Once you've written one test, it's easy to add more. You can create various helper methods to create the walls, player, etc. so that each test case shrinks down to a few lines.

[Here's a tutorial on unit testing.](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html#junit_intro)

**As an added bonus**, if you write a unit test you'll also have written an SSCCE :)